# Usando Portgues em Tenerife

Tags: portugués

I am going to Tenerife soon. I have no Spanish (apart from a few phrases) but have a basic level of conversational Portuguese, which I learned on Madeira.

Would Portuguese be understood on Tenerife?

Comment: There are parts of Tenerife extremely popular with English visitors especially older people escaping the UK winter so I would have thought English would be more useful than Portuguese.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es que si tienes contacto con la gente del lugar, hablas despacio y pronuncias claramente te entenderán en un 80% aproximadamente, en los sitios profesionales es normal que también te entiendan en inglés. Si fueras a Galicia  el tanto por ciento se elevaría, ya que el portugues procede en última instancia del gallego.

> A resposta curta é que se você tiver contato com a população local,
> falar devagar e pronunciar com clareza, eles vão te entender em
> aproximadamente 80%, em sites profissionais é normal que eles te
> entendam também em inglês. Se fosse para a Galiza, a percentagem
> aumentaria, já que o português acaba por vir do galego.

> The short answer is that if you have contact with the local people,
> speak slowly and pronounce clearly, they will understand you by
> approximately 80%, in professional sites it is normal that they also
> understand you in English. If you went to Galicia, the percentage would
> rise, since Portuguese ultimately comes from Galician.